# A weak convergence problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Erwin Kreyzsig's Introduction to Functional Analysis , Section 4.8- Problem2:

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces, $ T\in B(X,Y)$ and $(x_n)$ a sequence in X.
Prove that if $ \forall f\in X' \quad f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x_0)$, then $ \forall g \in Y' \quad g(Tx_n) \rightarrow g(Tx_0).$

I attempted as follows:
Consider
$$ |g(Tx_n) - g(Tx_0)  | \leq ||g||.||T||.|| x_n-x_0|| $$
I thought to replace $g$ with $T,  $ which would give me

$$  |g(Tx_n) - g(Tx_0)  | =| T(gx_n) - T(gx_0)| \leq ||T||.|g(x_n)-g(x_0)| $$ and conclusion directly follows. But I could not assure that what I did is correct.

Comment: Writing $g(x_n)$ doesn't make sense in general since $g$ is a functional defined on $Y$ whilst $x_n$ is a sequence in $X$ so you can't swap $T$ and $g$ as you have done.

Comment: I can't directly do that. But, as @Kenny have pointed out, If I show  $g\circ T$ is a linear and bounded operator from $X $ to $Y$. Then the result is immediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do $X'$ and $Y'$ denote the bounded linear functionals on $X$ and $Y$ respectively?

If so, I think the way to proceed is to show that if $g$ is a bounded linear functional on $Y$ and $T$ is a bounded operator from $X$ to $Y$, then $g \circ T$ is a bounded linear functional on $X$. Once you've done this, the result follows immediatedly by taking $f = g \circ T$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I can show that  $goT \in X'$ since $g$ and $T$ is linear bounded.